# Can we access the PropertyMetaData of any property in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way in kotlin to access the `PropertyMetaData` from outside of a property? To be more specific, from the delegation? 
Looking for something like this:

EDIT (a more suitable example now)

```
class Obj(var name : String = "")

class Bar {
 val prop1 : Obj by Inject.inject() // <- can inject() access prop1 without passing it explicitly?
 val prop2 : Obj by Inject.inject()
}

object Inject {

 val injected = arrayListOf<ReadOnlyProperty<Any, Obj>>()

 fun inject() : ReadOnlyProperty<Any, Obj> {

    val delegate = Delegates.lazy {
        Obj("NEED THE DELEGATED PROPERTY'S NAME HERE") // <- like "prop1" "prop2" ...
    }
    injected.add(delegate)
    return delegate
 }
}
```

EDIT (after 1.0.0-beta-1038)

This code snippet worked like a charm before (note: the String "scrollPlace" was not passed explicitly when using the previous version of kotlin since the property name was passed "implicitly" before):

```
val scrollPlace by injectBy<Image>("scrollPlace").replaceBy {

    val scrollPane = ScrollPane(VerticalGroup().space(12f).center())
    scrollPane.setPosition(it.x, it.y)
    scrollPane.setSize(it.width, it.height)
    scrollPane
}
```

In this example I'm using some chaining. The extension function injectBy (which is based on the pattern suggested under 1) of the accepted answer, except for passing a custom string ) creates a O2dInjectionClosure (ReadOnlyProperty) instance. The solution 1) would work of course, even though it's not as convenient as with the use of propertyDelgated, but the chaining causes some trouble. At least a proper solution haven't come to my mind yet. The extension function replaceBy creates another new O2dInjectionClosure instance:

```
 public final fun <T : Actor, R : Actor> O2dInjectionClosure<T>.replaceBy(replacer : (replaced : T) -> R) : O2dInjectionClosure<R> {
    val originalInitializer = this.initializer
    return O2dInjectionClosure { propName ->

        ... some transferring of the previous O2dInjectionClosure to this one
        new
    }
}
```

Thus, I somehow would like to do the necessary stuff on the last call of the chaining, but in a convenient way :).
I hope it's somehow reasonable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you need to invoke some initialization code on a delegate object for a property. There are several solutions:

1) Use the property reference expression, as noted by bashor, to obtain the name of the property and pass it to `inject`:

```
val prop1: Obj by Inject.inject(Bar::prop1.name)
val prop2: Obj by Inject.inject(Bar::prop2.name)
```

This is sort of verbose and error-prone, although explicit.

2) Do the initialization logic on the first access to the property. So `Inject` itself becomes a property delegate, maintaining the map of registered properties. However, there's a slight change in semantics that may not be applicable to your use case: at least one `get` is required for the property to be registered in `Inject`.

```
class Bar {
    val prop1: Obj by Inject
    val prop2: Obj by Inject
}

object Inject {
    val injected = hashMapOf<String, ReadOnlyProperty<Any, Obj>>()

    fun get(obj: Any, metadata: PropertyMetadata): Obj {
        // getOrPut computes and stores the value for the key if it's not present in the map
        val property = injected.getOrPut(metadata.name) {
            Delegates.lazy {
                Obj(metadata.name)
            }
        }

        return property[obj, metadata]
    }
}
```

3) (UPD: this is no longer supported.) Use the `propertyDelegated` method which is the *hidden and experimental* feature that allows your property delegate to be initialized with the metadata of the property which will use this delegate on access. Beware though that this method is likely to be renamed, redesigned or even removed in the future versions of Kotlin.

```
class Bar {
    val prop1: Obj by Inject
    val prop2: Obj by Inject
}

object Inject {
    val injected = hashMapOf<String, ReadOnlyProperty<Any, Obj>>()

    // Experimental method recognized and called by Kotlin on delegated property initialization
    fun propertyDelegated(metadata: PropertyMetadata) {
        injected[metadata.name] = Delegates.lazy {
            Obj(metadata.name)
        }
    }

    fun get(obj: Any, metadata: PropertyMetadata): Obj {
        return injected[metadata.name]!!.get(obj, metadata)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer!! Actually the last solution is exactly the one I was looking for. Since in the previous solutions I'm forced to call the properties at least once in order to have the "injection" registered in val injected. I will take potential changes into account :)

Comment: since the recent prerelease propertyDelegated seems not to get called anymore. Did a renaming or removal happen?

Comment: Indeed, it has been temporarily disabled until 1.0. It is planned to be redesigned in the future version of Kotlin though. As for your question, I guess my first solution should work for you.

Comment: Is there a way to imitate the propertyDelegate method call manually? Unfortunately the first two solutions are not a real match for my use case. I somehow need to catch the point, when the delegation is initialized, at least handle all the properties from a class which uses delegation (by reflection?).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why the first solution does not work for you? You can declare `fun inject(p: KProperty<*>): Inject` in the `Inject` object which would do the initialization stuff and return the object itself, and use it like in the sample I provided above.